# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with implement GCM

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, xcode7.1

I'm new to iOS development.
I use GCM for chating and push notifications.
When I run my iOS app in simulator it never gives me any error but when I run my iOS app on my device(iPad, iOS 8.1, xcode7.1), the build fails and gives an error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) )
```

How should I deal with the error?

Comment: Please post your solution first. What have you tried, what went wrong?

Comment: Post Your error scrrenshot

Comment: i use GCM for push notification in iphone app so i follow " https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client " this and get this error

Comment: it seems that you have added two library of files twice..are you using cocoapods ? what else library did you use

Comment: with cocoa pods i use 
 GGLInstanceID (1.1.1):
 Google/CloudMessaging (1.2.1):
 Google/Core 
Google/SignIn
 GoogleAppUtilities 
GoogleAuthUtilities
GoogleCloudMessaging
GoogleInterchangeUtilities   
GoogleIPhoneUtilities (1.0.0):
 GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
 GoogleSignIn
GoogleAppUtilities
 GoogleAuthUtilities
 GoogleNetworkingUtilities
 GoogleUtilities

Comment: Please try this: go to the project settings (click on the File Structure icon and then the app name, and then the Tests target), click `Build Settings` and then scroll down until you see `Test Host` (or type ‘host’ in the search box). Then `clear` the contents of both the Debug and Release hosts, circled below. The app should then compile without any issues. For more details please refer to here:http://www.robpercival.co.uk/upgrading-apps-to-xcode-7-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1/

Comment: in my xcode there is no contents in both Debug and Release . so what i clear.